# Trouble calling a custom object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC.NET 4 site:

In HomeController.cs I have created a new object (I referred to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173110.aspx) to help me with that), Story, which will hold Strings *title* and *author*. Here's that code:

```
namespace Site.Controllers
{
    public class Story
    {
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public String Author { get; set; }
        public Story(string title, string author)
        {
            Title = title;
            Author = author;
        }
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public Story Story1 = new Story("Test title", "Test author");
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This all seems to be working - I'm not getting any errors anyway - but when I try to use it in a cshtml file, I'm getting an error. Here's where the error occurs (in articles.cshtml):

```
<h1>@Site.Controllers.HomeController.Story.Title</h1>
```

And the error is

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or 
property 'Site.Controllers.HomeController.Story1'
```

How do I properly use this title I've defined elsewhere?

Another concern is: will I only be able to use the title while on the Home page? I need it to be accessible throughout the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Story story1 = new Story("Test title", "Test author");
        return View(story1);
    }
}
```

...

```
@model Site.Controllers.HomeController.Story
<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
```

That said, if you want `story1` to be statically accessible from other pages in the site, or even other controller actions on the server, you could construct a `static` model:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public static Story Story1 = new Story("Test title", "Test author");

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Story1);
    }

    public ActionResult Action2()
    {
        return View(Story1);
    }

    public ActionResult ActionN()
    {
        return View(Story1);
    }
}
```

With the above, you could also do something like this:

```
<h1>@Site.Controllers.HomeController.Story1.Title</h1>
```

**Update**

I am not suggesting the use of a `static` model here. From reading it is clear that the OP does not understand the difference between an object class and an object instance, or at least where that difference lies in C#. The CSHTML error was trying to get to the story title statically, which it could not because the property was not static.

I believe the answer to this question is not so much MVC101, but rather C#101 or even OOP101.

Comment: -1 for suggesting the use of a `static` model here, there is almost never a good reason for using it (the one suggested is certainly doesn't justify it).

Comment: @James agreed, I can't think of many reasons to use a static model either. I was trying to point out the reason for the exception in the OP, that an object reference was required, and that you could only get to one on the HomeController class by making `Story` a `static` member. Though the second part of my answer is not recommended, it will at least not throw the exception mentioned in the OP.

Comment: My comment regarding MVC 101 was referring to the recommended approach for passing models from the controller to the view - which is *entirely* MVC-related. The fact that the OP is using C# here irrelevant as is OOP in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong, and in fact, would never work in the way you expect anyway. The main reason being controllers are only available for the lifetime of the request, therefore by the time the view is being rendered the controller would have been disposed.

Also, it's violating one of the fundamentals of using MVC in the first place by coupling your view with your controller. What you *should* be doing here is passing your model *into* your view as a parameter i.e.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new Story("Test title", "Test author"));
}
```

The model passed to the cshtml file is then accessible from the `Model` property of the view

```
@model Site.Controllers.HomeController.Story

<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
```

This is MVC 101 really.

Comment: Where do I define the title and author?

Comment: Oh, I guess I create a new file called Story.cs, and put it in Models, and define story there instead of in the controller?

Comment: @TravisHeeter I think you are confusing the model class with the model class instance. Go buy a good MVC book, it will answer this along with your next 100 questions.

Comment: @TravisHeeter yes that's the idea. Although, it shouldn't really matter *where* `Story.cs` goes, just as long as the class is within scope so that you can reference it from your view.

Comment: OK, I got it to work. I moved Story to Models/Story.cs, but I used a static instance to create Story1 in the Controller. It works, but I'm wondering if there's a "better" way to do it? Like should I define the Title/Author in the View?

Comment: Well the better way is definitely to not use a `static` instance. Where are you pulling the `title` / `author` from? I presume it's coming from the view?

Comment: public static Story Story1 = new Story("Test Title", "Test Author") in the controller.

Comment: @TravisHeeter that's obviously just sample data, I mean in the real app where would *"Test Title"* & *"Test Author"* be coming from? A database? Regardless, you would want to create your `story` instance inside the action rather than making it static across the entire controller (see the example in my answer).

Comment: @James As of now it doesn't connect to a data source. It is slated for the far distant future, but it's not a priority for now. I would like to set it up so the transition would be easier. Does that mean I should define it in the Controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63556/discussion-between-travis-heeter-and-james).

Comment: -1 for not explaining why the CSHTML exception was thrown due to razor markup in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems in that code...

1.) 2 classes in one file. Class `Story` shouldn't be in namespace Controllers all, it doesn't make any sense. Please refer to OOP principles and good programming practices.

2.) you try to refer to your value like this `<h1>@Site.Controllers.HomeController.Story.Title</h1>`
but this would mean that there's a static property/variable in HomeController class and you want to get it's property/variable, but that's not the case, is it?

Easiest fix is to pass the value to the view as part of the model

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View(Story1);
}
```

Now you can access the value like this:

```
@model pathToClass.Story
<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
```

I'd really argue against using static variable in web development, because later you may have a requirement to support different languages etc., and it will become one untestable mess. Always try to use instances whenever possible, especially when dealing with web applications.

3.) work on your naming conventions.. Story1 is really a poor choice.